# How to check that a jQuery easing method is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I check to see that a specific easing method is defined?  For example, jQuery includes two methods ("linear" and "swing"), jQuery UI has a bunch more and there are also third-party plugins that have even more methods.  In my plugin, I let developers specify an easing method but it is up to them to include the proper files which define those methods, so I want to check and display an error if they have specified an easing method which does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should be as easy as:

```
jQuery.easing['swing'] != undefined    // -> true
jQuery.easing['foobar'] != undefined   // -> false
```

Comment: FYI, you can also use dot notation which I prefer - jQuery.easing.foobar

Comment: Yep. I chose this syntax since I figured you might want to use variables for keys, which the dot notation doesn't allow you to do naturally.